# Употребление предлогов со словом «контрапункт»

Tags: предлоги

Как вы думаете, с каким предлогом в данном случае лучше употребить слово «контрапункт»?

*Ее голос звучал контрапунктом к завываниям ветра (в контрапункте с завываниями) ветра.*